# How to configure Latex Ubuntu18.04 for tcexam

Tags: latex, localhost

So, i installed tcexam in localhost. I tried to made test for students. But, when i write mathematic formula with Latex, i got [image: this]

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: You may want to use [LyX](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lyx) for formula writing on Ubuntu and then copy/paste them to TCExam web-service.